# Move vm from vmplayer 12 to vm workstation 14 pro

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

I have a virtual machine I've been using in vmWare Workstation Player 12 for a couple years. I'd like to get Workstation Pro 14, but before I do, is there a special process for migrating a vm from player 12 to pro 14?

Answer (score 1):

No process was needed. Simply installing Workstation Pro 14 was all that was needed. It saw and loaded the vms I had with no issues.